# Exact same text strings not matching

Tags: python, string, pandas, dataframe, character-encoding

I have two columns in a dataframe `title` and `store` containing text strings by which I want to subset the dataframe:

```
In [84]:
    2631              coffee‑mate sugar free french ...  jet.com
    2633            nestle coffeemate natural bliss ...  jet.com
    2634         coffee‑mate liquid coffee creamer, ...  jet.com
    3085                       coffee‑mate hazelnut ...  jet.com
```

When I try :

```
df[(df.title.str.contains('coffee-mate')) & (df.store.str.contains('jet.com'))]
```

I get:

```
Out[84]: 
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [title, store]
Index: []
```

However, when I do this:

```
df[(df.title.str.contains('coffee')) & (df.store.str.contains('jet.com'))]
```

I get:

```
    2631              coffee‑mate sugar free french ...  jet.com
    2633            nestle coffeemate natural bliss ...  jet.com
    2634         coffee‑mate liquid coffee creamer, ...  jet.com
    3085                       coffee‑mate hazelnut ...  jet.com
```

I don't know what to make of this !

I tried copying the characters 'coffee-mate' to do an equivalency test and got `False`.

```
'coffee‑mate' == 'coffee-mate'
Out[92]: False
```

I have a feeling this is something to do with encoding but don't know how to detect and fix the issue. Can someone help?

Comment: the left hand side contains an underscore character and the right hand side contains a hyphen. You didn't copy-paste the same text to both sides.

Comment: @hobs there's no underscore character - someone wrongly edited the question and changed all non-breaking hyphens to underscores. I wonder how to call moderator attention to this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The "coffee-mate" in your dataframe uses a non-breaking hyphen (`u"\u2011"`), and your search string uses a hyphen

Non breaking
http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%E2%80%91&mode=char

Your hyphen
http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=-&mode=char

While they look the same to you and me, Python considers them two different characters. If you have this issue in the future, I solved this just by copy pasting the character into this [UTF8 tool](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi) - you were wise to run a comparison of `coffee-mate` and `coffee‑mate`